# Assign foreign key in DRF POST request

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

How I can directly add user which already login, when I create company?

**Models:**

```
 class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company,  on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                blank=True, null=True
```

**View:**

```
class CompanySetupView(ModelViewSet):
     queryset = Company.objects.all()
     permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
     serializer_class = CompanySetupSerializer
```

**Serializer**:

```
class CompanySetupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: do you want to assign authorized user to created company ?

Comment: yep! @A'zamMamatmurodov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try add this method to your serializer And test it ?

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    request = self.context['request']
    user = request.user
    company = super().create(validated_data)
    user.company = company
    user.save()
    return company
```

Comment: it helps to others who has same the situation

Comment: Yes I checked as answer not enough rep for it:D for showing